# Python URL call using xdg Linux command

Tags: python, linux

I have been trying to get this simple url call Linux command to run as a python script. However, I keep getting an error for too many arguments in the system() module. Is there is easy fix still using this technique?

```
import sys
import os
g = str(input('enter search '))
os.system('xdg-open https://',g)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

format the command as a single string instead of 2 parameters

```py
import sys 
import os

search = str(input('enter search')) 
os.system(f'xdg-open https://{search}')
```

Comment: You my friend are gersh dernd rock star!